# php: Extract text between specific tags from a webpage

Tags: php, regex, html-parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best methods to parse HTML with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html-with-php)

I understand I should be using a html parser like php domdocument (http://docs.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) or tagsoup.

How would I use php domdocument to extract text between specific tags, for example get text between h1,h2,h3,p,table? It seems I can only do this for one tag only with getelementbytagname.

Is there a better html parser for such task? Or how would I loop through the php domdocument?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are correct, use DomDocument (since regex is NOT a good idea for parsing HTML. Why? See [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#answer-1732454) for reasons why).

`getElementsByTagName` gives you a [DOMNodeList](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domnodelist.php) that you can iterate over to get the text of all the found elements. So, your code could look something like:

```
$document = new \DOMDocument();
$document->loadHTML($html);

$tags = array ('h1', 'h2', 'h3', 'h4', 'p');
$texts = array ();
foreach($tags as $tag)
{
  $elementList = $document->getElementsByTagName($tag);
  foreach($elementList as $element)
  {
     $texts[$element->tagName][] = $element->textContent;
  }
}
return $texts;
```

Note that you should probably have some error handling in there, and you will also lose the context of the texts, but you can probably edit this code as you see fit.

Comment: Thanks, looks good. Tried it on a few webpages, like yahoo.com (just added `$html = file_get_contents("http://yahoo.com");`, but it always fails and gives the dreaded `domdocument.loadhtml</a>]: htmlParseEntityRef: expecting ';' in Entity` I guess will have to check out tagsoup or simplehtmldom. :) The algo looks good though.

Answer (score 0):

You can doing so with a regex.

```
preg_match_all('#<h1>([^<]*)</h1>#Usi', $html_string, $matches);
foreach ($matches as $match)
{
  // do something with $match
}
```

Comment: Please don't use regex for this!  Regex is notoriously bad at parsing HTML with any reliability.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what is your source so I added a function to get the content via the URL.

```
$file = file_get_contents($url);

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($file);

$body = $doc->getElementsByTagName('body');
$h1 = $body->getElementsByTagName('h1');
```

I am not sure of this part:

```
for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
    echo $items->item($i)->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Or:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    echo $item->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

Here is more info on nodeValue: http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.domnode-node-value.php

Hope it helps!